# How can I use the .NET upgrade Assistant?

Tags: upgrade, .net-8.0, assistant

I am using the .NET Upgrade Assistant to upgrade project from .NET Core 3.0 to .NET 8.0.

I am using the in-place project upgrade.

[image]

I check the dependencies on and run the upgrade project. At the end I got an error:

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException,    場所 Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.d__68.MoveNext()...

and in the `.csproj` file, I see this error:

[image]

It turns the `BaseOutputPath` into 2 lines, and the project should not reload.

Why does this happen? And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you try just to remove that manually and reload project ?

Comment: i see. the BaseOutputPath is not a right tag in the *.csProject!
Thank you